# Error referencia circular

Tags: java, spring-security

Tengo este error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
```

Os dejo las clases

```
  @Service
public class ServiciosJwtUsuarios implements ServicioJwtUsuario {

    @Autowired
    private MedicoRepository medicoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PacienteRepository pacienteRepository;

    private UserDetails cargarMedicoPorIdentificador(String identificador) {
        Optional<Medico> optMedico = medicoRepository.findById(identificador);
        if (!optMedico.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Usuario no encontrado con identificador: " + identificador);
        }
        Medico m = optMedico.get();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(m.getnLicencia(), m.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    private UserDetails cargarPacientePorIdentificador(String identificador) {
        Optional<Paciente> optPaciente = pacienteRepository.findById(identificador);
        Paciente p = optPaciente.get();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(p.getnSS(), p.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String identificador) {
        if (identificador.startsWith("m")) {
            return cargarMedicoPorIdentificador(identificador);
        } else if (identificador.startsWith("es")) {
            return cargarPacientePorIdentificador(identificador);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
    
@Service("ServiciosMedicoI")
public class ServiciosMedico implements ServiciosMedicoI {

    @Autowired
    private MedicoRepository repositorioM;
    @Autowired
    private HospitalRepository repositorioH;
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public List<Medico> buscarTodosM() {
        return repositorioM.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveMedico(Medico medico1) {
        medico1.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(medico1.getPassword()));
        repositorioM.save(medico1);
    }

    @Override
    public void eliminarMedico(String nLicencia) throws ExcepcionServicio {
        Optional<Medico> optMedico = repositorioM.findById(nLicencia);
        if (!optMedico.isPresent()) {
            throw new ExcepcionServicio("El numero de Licencia no existe");
        }
        repositorioM.deleteById(nLicencia);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Medico> buscarMedico(String nLicencia) throws ExcepcionServicio {
        Optional<Medico> optMedico = repositorioM.findById(nLicencia);
        if (!optMedico.isPresent()) {
            throw new ExcepcionServicio("El numero de Licencia no existe");
        }
        return optMedico;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Paciente> BuscarPacientesXMedico(String nLicencia) throws ExcepcionServicio {
        List<Paciente> listaPacientes = repositorioM.BuscarPacientesXMedico(nLicencia);
        if (listaPacientes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ExcepcionServicio("El numero de Licencia no existe");
        }
        return listaPacientes;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Medico> BuscarMedicoXEspecialidad(String especialidad, String hospital) throws ExcepcionServicio {
        Optional<Hospital> optHospital = repositorioH.findById(hospital);
        if (!optHospital.isPresent()) {
            throw new ExcepcionServicio("El hospital no existe");
        }
        List<Medico> listaMedico = repositorioM.BuscarMedicoXEspecialidad(especialidad, hospital);
        if (listaMedico.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ExcepcionServicio("No hay medicos con esa especialidad");
        }
        return listaMedico;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Medico> BuscarMedicosXHospital(String hospital) throws ExcepcionServicio {
        List<Medico> listaMedico = repositorioM.BuscarMedicosXHospital(hospital);
        if (listaMedico.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ExcepcionServicio("No hay medicos en el hospital");
        }
        return listaMedico;
    }
}



       Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final JwtPuntoDAutentificacion jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final ServiciosJwtUsuarios jwtUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    public WebSecurityConfig(JwtPuntoDAutentificacion jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint,
            ServiciosJwtUsuarios jwtUserDetailsService, JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint = jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.jwtUserDetailsService = jwtUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/autenticacion/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return httpSecurity.build();

    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "*" }));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(
                Arrays.asList(new String[] { "HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS" }));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "*" }));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "X-Auth-Token", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" }));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
 */
```

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

```
@Autowired
private ServiciosJwtUsuarios jwtUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtToken jwtTokenUtil;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    String identifier = null;
    String jwtToken = null;
    if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
        try {
            identifier = jwtTokenUtil.obtenerIdentificadorDelToken(jwtToken);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("No se pudo obtener el identificador del token JWT", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("El token JWT ha expirado", e);
        }
    }
    if (identifier != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(identifier);
        if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                    .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

}
no consigo eliminarla por mas que lo itnento

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregar la anotación `@Lazy` a la declaración de su `AuthenticationProvider`. La anotación retrasará la creación del `bean` hasta que sea necesario, lo que debería evitar la referencia circular.

También puedes inyectar `MedicoRepository` y `PacienteRepository` directamente, en un constructor para evitar el problema de referencia circular. Por ejemplo:

```
@Service
public class ServiciosJwtUsuarios implements ServicioJwtUsuario {

    private final MedicoRepository medicoRepository;
    private final PacienteRepository pacienteRepository;

    public ServiciosJwtUsuarios(MedicoRepository medicoRepository, PacienteRepository pacienteRepository) {
        this.medicoRepository = medicoRepository;
        this.pacienteRepository = pacienteRepository;
    }

    // Resto del código...
}

@Service("ServiciosMedicoI")
public class ServiciosMedico implements ServiciosMedicoI {

    private final MedicoRepository repositorioM;
    private final HospitalRepository repositorioH;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public ServiciosMedico(MedicoRepository repositorioM, HospitalRepository repositorioH, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.repositorioM = repositorioM;
        this.repositorioH = repositorioH;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    // Resto del código...
}
```

Comment: Como extra tampoco es necesario que tenga definido, el bean de               "@Bean public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() " y al mismo tiempo este haciendo un Autowired de                                                     "public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)"               con que tenga uno ya es suficiente

Comment: Concuerdo contigo :)